# How to display a models attribute in a read only text area

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, devise

For background I am using Ruby on Rails with the Devise gem. One of the Users attributes is a string called bio. My goal is for a profile page to display the bio in a read only text box. I feel the lines the text box displays gives a nice aesthetic. I am also using bootstrap.

**Pages Controller:**

```
def profile
      user=User.all
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :profile, locals: { user: user } }
      end
    end
```

**The code for my profile.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-5">
      <%= current_user.text_area :bio, readonly: true %>%
   </div>
```

The error I am getting is NoMethodError in Pages#profile - undefined method `text_area'

Comment: text_area is not the attribute of the user, it is the attribute of the form. Use this
`<%= f.text_area :bio, readonly: true %>`

Comment: @Naveed it returns an error: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `f'

Comment: I think you're not using it in the form in that case use this syntax  `<%= text_area_tag :bio, current_user.bio, readonly: true %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css in order to achieve the same result as text_area. Place your current_user.bio attribute in a `<p>` or `<div>` element and give specific width to that element so the line can break. For example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-5">
        <p class='specific-width'> <%= current_user.bio %> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in css file:

```
.specific-width{
    width: 30px;
}
```